# WordPress custom query - hide empty meta

Tags: php, wordpress, mysqli

I have the following code in a WordPress custom query, but in the query I want to hide all results where the meta `'price'` is empty.

```
    $args['meta_key']       =   'title';
    $args['orderby']        =   'meta_value_num';
    $args['order']          =   'ASC';
    $args['cache_results']  =   false;
    $args['update_post_meta_cache']  =   false;
    $args['update_post_term_cache']  =   false;

    $prop_selection = new WP_Query($args);
```

Comment: You don't refer to a meta 'price' in your example code.  Please post the relevant code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're looking for [meta_query](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Custom_Field_Parameters). The below will exclude items that have price set to blank or zero:

```
$args['meta_query'] = array(
   array(
      'key' => 'price',
      'value' => array('', 0),
      'compare' => 'NOT IN'
   )
)
```

Comment: Thank you, you absolute legend! It worked like a charm!